# GA4 client_id Dimension and BigQuery user_pseudo_id Showing as N/A

Tags: google-bigquery, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, clientid

Problem Description:

The client_id dimension in GA4 reports and user_pseudo_id in BigQuery are displaying as 1.111111n/a or n/a, despite efforts to resolve the issue.

Steps Taken: Attempted troubleshooting by deleting the Measurement Protocol in the GA4 property, adding client_id with the GTAG GET API template, and modifying the GTM Configuration tag to exclude the client_id from event parameter.

Expected Outcome: The client-id dimension and user_pseudo_id should display accurate data (without n/a and 1.1.1111111..) in both GA4 reports and BigQuery.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqxdF.png)